# Less count of rows inserted to big query table than expected

Tags: google-bigquery

I have inserted 71 rows to day partitioned table. After streaming buffer workers processes there are only 48 rows in my table. I know that there are deduplication process, but the rows were different. I've tried to check how the rows look in streaming buffer and I've set condition to get results with _PARTITIONTIME set to NULL. I've got nothing.

I have no idea how is it working.

//Edit:
I've inserted data using insertRows method from cloud-bigquery library.
I'm selecting rows by using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table$20180216]
```

Comment: How did you insert your data and how are you querying it? You can add this info to your post by editing it

Comment: I've edited post and I've added this info to my post

Comment: As a side note, it's recommended to use standard SQL:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE _PARTITIONDATE = "2018-02-16"
You can enable standard SQL clicking on the Show Options in the UI. More information: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql

Answer (score 2):

If you set _PARTITIONTIME to NULL, it selects 0 partitions and therefore 0 rows. Try querying the partition you inserted rows into by setting _PARTITIONDATE = "2018-02-15" (or change to the date you need).

Comment: I've set _PARTITIONDATE to "2018-02-15" but it returns me zero rows. I had to change the string date to the timestamp because _PARTITIONDATE is int32 type(maybe this affected on the result of the query). When I've added partition date to the name of the table then I've got rows from this date, but there is also less rows then expected(I've inserted 71 rows to the streaming buffer, and I have 23 rows in preview right now).

Comment: The most reliable way to get all the rows from the table including streaming buffer is using query. I'm not sure if table preview includes streaming buffer. However, if you inserted them yesterday they should be there by now. Can you include the code you use for streaming inserts and how you check the status of the operation?

Comment: Also, do you see all the rows if you just run select * from table ?

Comment: I solved it, it was my mistake. I have batch process in my query worker and after truncating batched rows the autoincrement was duplicating insert ids.